# How to Add Pointer Record in Reverse Lookup DNS Zone (Windows Server)

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, reverse-dns, ptr-record

I want to add a pointer record in reverse lookup zone in windows 2012 Server. The pointer record should point to a delegated zone defined in a forward lookup zone.

I want to answer any DNS query: `b._dns-sd._udp.0.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa PTR`

My answer should be:

`b._dns-sd._udp.0.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa PTR device-discovery.testzone.local.`

I already have device-discovery delegation defined in testzone.local. which works fine.

Can someone please guide me how to add this PTR record in reverse lookup zone. Please comment in case of any question.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this with the dnscmd command:

```
dnscmd 127.0.0.1 /RecordAdd 0.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. b._dns-sd._udp PTR device-discovery.testzone.local.
```